# Wake up PC via USB from another PC

Tags: linux, power-supply, desktop-computer

How can I wake up/turn on Linux powered PC from another Linux powered PC via mutual USB cable?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to actually do this might be via **two** USB ethernet cards and WakeOnLan.

PC - USB_NIC ---------(ethernet cable) ---------- **non**-USB_NIC -PC to be woken up.

Which only works one way and which seriously deviates from USB.
(Heck, the forst USB NIC does not even need to be USB based).

Direct USB to USB is propably not an option because USB is split into master and slave.
(This is why USB cables have two different headings; one plug for masters, one plug for slaves. This prevents you from plugging in two masters or two slaves on a cable. And it is not just a matter of changing the cable, the actual USB chipset and drivers need to understand their part and only a few of them are capable or both master and slave mode)

Comment: Does WakeOnLan must be supported by motherboard?

Comment: I suspect I may have had a brain fart. WoL via and USB NIC might not work if the PC powers down and also takes the power of the USB bus. It *might* still work from standby or sleep though, but not from a full power down.